# Excel - how do I retrieve corresponding values from another worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a "DETAIL" worksheet which tallies numbers:

**DETAIL WORKSHEET**

> ```
>               (Column A)  (Column E)
> (Excel Row #) DATE        TOTAL
> ...
> 700          6/8/2015    =sum(D701:D709)
> 701   
> 702
> 703
> 704  
> 705
> 706
> 707
> 708  
> 709
> 710         6/9/2015    =sum(D711:D719)
> ...
> ```

I want to retrieve the TOTAL from Column E in the Detail Worksheet from another sheet

```
(Column A)   (Column B)
DATE         DETAIL TOTAL
...
6/8/2015    =sum(Details!E700)
6/9/2015    =sum(Details!E710)
...
```

What I would like to be able to do is to select `=sum(Details!E700)` and `=sum(Details!E710)` and have it autocomplete down the next cells:

```
=sum(Details!E720)
=sum(Details!E730)
=sum(Details!E740)
=sum(Details!E750)
...
```

It's not working because the original figures are ten cells apart from each other, and I can't figure out how to autocomplete this task to retrieve them all successfully. How do I retrieve the right values from the original sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the simplest solution would be to just use a `VLOOKUP`.

E.g. in cell `B5` on your new sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP($A5,'Details'!$A$2:$E$1000,5)
```

This searches the first column (the dates) of range `A2:E1000` on your original sheet for the date you've got in `A5` on your new sheet, and then returns the corresponding value 5 columns across (ie column `E`)